# Is there a way to get user's UID on Linux machine using java?

Tags: java, linux, uid

Is there a way to get user's UID on Linux machine using java? I'm aware of `System.getProperty("user.name");` method, but it return's user name and I'm looking for UID.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can execute `id` command and read result.

for example:

`$ id -u jigar`

output:

> 1000

you can execute command by

```
try {
    String userName = System.getProperty("user.name");
    String command = "id -u "+userName;
    Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

    // Get the input stream and read from it
    InputStream in = child.getInputStream();
    int c;
    while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
        process((char)c);
    }
    in.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

[source](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.lang/ReadFromCommand.html)

Comment: It would be much easier to parse if you executed "id -n"

Comment: `id -u <user>` will only print the UID.

Comment: The OP already has the username from `System.getProperty("user.name")`.

Comment: @Anto there are lots of possibility to play with it

Answer (score 11):

There is actually an api for this. There is no need to call a shell command or use JNI, just

```
def uid = new com.sun.security.auth.module.UnixSystem().getUid()
```

Comment: This looks to be Oracle specific and does not work with OpenJDK

Comment: Works in OpenJDK too, tested on java-11-openjdk-devel-11.0.3.7

Comment: On Mac and Linux, I am in doubt about Solaris though.

Comment: However not an option under Java 8.

Answer (score 6):

If you can influence how the Java VM is started, you could handover the *uid* as a user property:

```
java -Duserid=$(id -u) CoolApp
```

In your CoolApp, you could simply fetch the ID with:

```
System.getProperty("userid");
```

Regards,

Martin.

Answer (score 2):

Another choice would be calling getuid() using JNI.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the sake of completeness, here is a Java-only solution without any need for JNI, child processes or private API.

**A word of warning**: This relies on the user home directory, which is not at all required to match the owner of the currently running Java process. Be sure about your targeted system environment, before blindly relying on this:

```java
Path userHome = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"));
int uid = (Integer)Files.getAttribute(userHome, "unix:uid")
```

Comment: On some systems (e.g. Linux) `(Integer)Files.getAttribute(Paths.get("/proc/self"), "unix:uid")` works for running process's UID

Answer (score 1):

Just open the `/etc/passwd` file and search for the line that has a user equal to `System.getProperty("user.name")`.

Comment: that does not work on systems using other methods for keeping the user database e.g. [NIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Information_Service) or [LDAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol) etc. (typically used on clusters)