# how to get userid and gid in gradle?

Tags: gradle

I can do this in the `build.gradle`:

```
println System.getProperty("user.name")
```

How do I get user ID and primary group ID for current user in a Linux machine?

Capturing the output of `exec` is the last thing I want to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796172

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Gradle doesn't provide such functionality out-of-the-box, however running commands in groovy is fairly easy. Below sample gradle script that does the job:

```
def username = System.properties['user.name']
println "Username $username"
def uid = ["id", "-u", username].execute().text.trim()
println "UID: $uid"
def gid = ["id", "-g", username].execute().text.trim()
println "GID: $gid"
```

Comment: To get the id of current user, just omit the username altogether.

Answer (score 5):

There is an api for this kind of thing actually

```
def uid = new com.sun.security.auth.module.UnixSystem().getUid()
```

How to do it on Windows? I have no idea

Comment: However not an option under Java 8.